# Add legend to the chart control of c#

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization, mschart

I am developing an `asp.net-mvc4` web application in `Visual Studio-2010` in which I am accessing data from SQL server and making some line and `pie-charts` for better and interactive view. Line chart does not have any problem and works fine. I also need to make `pie-chart` amonth three values to make comparison. I making a `pie-chart` out my data as below

```
var c =  new Chart(width: 450, height: 350)
            //.AddTitle("Energy Consumption Plot")
            .AddLegend("E - Maschine", "Nebenverbraucher", "PTC")
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Pie",

            yValues: new[] {Maschine, Nebenverbraucher, PTC})
            .GetBytes("png")
            ;

        return File(c, "image/png");
```

Following figure shows the `pie-chart` generated from above code.

[image]

As I have three different variable in the pie chart, I want to see all in the legend but it only shows the first one. Why it shows the points?

Later, I modified the code, I enabled xValue with following code,

```
 var c =  new Chart(width: 450, height: 350)
            //.AddTitle("Energy Consumption Plot")
            .AddLegend()
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Pie",
            xValue: new[] { "E - Maschine", "Nebenverbraucher", "PTC" },
            yValues: new[] {Maschine, Nebenverbraucher, PTC})
            .GetBytes("png")
            ;

        return File(c, "image/png");
```

Output becomes

[image]

Seems to be good, But now another undesired thing, I dont want to see the text inside the `pie-chart`. How could I only show the legend values outside the chart no inside.

Comment: which charting library is this?

Comment: its Chart library of C#

Comment: I don't understand how the output picture is different than what you want.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes it is MSChart

Comment: @gunr2171 It is strange. I want to just show all three names of my variable agians colour. If I enable the xValue that is currently commented, i get all three but inside the pic. I have edited the question with xValue enabled please check.

Answer (score 0):

I am still waiting for the solution of my problem but I generated `pie-chart` by another way. Generating plots by this is automated. I am unable to make some changes manually. For example it shows the percentage value on the chart when mouse hovers over the chart. It also rounds off the value of the portion, which is also annoying. Is there any way to stop round off in the google script? I used google javascript to make pie plot. This plot is more dynamic and have very good visibility as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {


      var EMachine = 0.0;
      var Neben = 0.0;


        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['E-Maschine', @ViewBag.EMachine],
      ['Nebenverbraucher', @ViewBag.Neben],
      ['PTC', @ViewBag.ptc],
      ]);

        var options = {
            title: ''
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

and plot looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you only have the single series in your chart, if you want to hide the labels for it, try this.

```
c.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
```

See if that does the trick.